# EXTJS: Displaying Custom Tooltips Over Grid Cells

Tags: extjs, menu, tooltip

How would I display a custom tool tip (like a Menu) over a grid cell when the mouse hovers over it? It has to be dynamic as each cell can have different menu items in the tool tip. I need to know the event to listen for as well as how to use a custom Menu instead of a typical text string or HTML template-based tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

Get the grid in which tooltip is to be added.

```
var grid = Ext.componentQuery.query('grid[itemId=name_of_grid]')[0];
```

while creating a tooltip pass the class name & the target in which the tooltip is to be shown.

```
grid.tip = Ext.Create('Ext.tip.Tooltip',{
title : 'title',
itemId : 'itemId',
target : grid.el,
delegate : 'x-grid-cell' // the cell class in which the tooltip has to be triggered
trackMouse : true,
renderTo : Ext.getBody()});
```

Now create a function that handles the render of the tooltip

```
var tipRenderer = function (e, t, grid){
e.stopEvent();
var tipbody = '<h5> helo </h5>';
grid.tip.update(tipbody);
grid.tip.show();
});
```

Now, raise the tip on mouseover event.

```
grid.getEl().on('mouseover', function(e,t,a){
    tipRenderer(e,t,grid);
}, null, {delegate:targetClass});
```

**NOTE**: all these code has to be executed after the grid has been rendered.

---

Shakti

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives you a tip object for each grid row together with the associated record.

```
listeners: {
      render: function(grid) {
            grid.view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: grid.getEl(),
            // Each grid row causes its own seperate show and hide.
            delegate: ".x-grid-cell-last",
            items: [], // add items later based on the record
            // Render immediately so that tip.body can be referenced prior to the first show.
            listeners: {
                // Change content dynamically depending on which element triggered the show.
                beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                        var rec = grid.view.getRecord(Ext.get(tip.triggerElement).findParentNode('.x-grid-row'));                        
                        grid.fireEvent('rowhover', tip, rec);
                        return true;
                }}
        });
     }}
```

And then in your controller class you can listen to the hover event and add anything you like to the tip container. In your case you can configure a custom menu from the passed `rec` record and add it to the tip. Call this function on the `rowhover`event:

```
function onHover(tip, rec) {
    var me = this,
    tip.removeAll(true) // autodestroy
    tip.add(Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
        items:[/* your config here */]              
       );
}
```

I guess instead of a tip object you could also directly configure a menu object in the listener of your grid.